# How to append non numbers in a <p> tag, and clear the binded element in svelte

Tags: javascript, svelte

I am building a calculator app and need to append numbers to a display. I also need to either append a non-number like * /, or clear the display and use a function to do that. Both don't work because I can't clear the display or append non-numbers to the display. Thanks in advance!

Heres part of my code-

`<script> let displayobj = 0; </script>`

Then having

```
<p  id ="display" bind:this={displayobj}></p>
```

In the display
It works for numbers like this
`<button class="button" on:click={displayobj.append(9)}>9 </button>`

But It doesn't work for non numbers like* / - + symbols, and gives me a red line when i do this
`<button class="button" on:click={displayobj.append(*)}>*</button>`

Also when I try to clear the number like this

`<button class="button" on:click={displayobj = 0}>Clear</button>`

It doesn't work and freezes
my code so I can't append anything anymore.

So I tried to have a function do it like this

`<button class="button" on:click={clear}>Clear</button>`

Then having this

`<script> function clear(){ displayobj = 0; }</script>`

But that didn't work either can you tell me why? Thank you!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but your code just doesn't seem like following the logic and principles of Svelte.

#1: In Svelte, you very rarely need to access and/or manipulate DOM elements directly. You let the Svelte directives do that for you.

So instead of getting a reference to the `<P>` tag, you simply create a string variable on the top level and insert it with a mustache syntax inside the `<P>` tag, like so:

```
<script>
let display="0"
</script>
<p>{display}</p>
```

After this you only need to manipulate the value of the `display` variable and the displayed value will change. A LOT easier than monkeying around with DOM manipulations.

#2: The `on:click={___}` expects a function reference, not a statement. If you don't want to define loads of one-time-use simple functions then you can use the arrow function syntax to define an unnamed function right there.

Example:

WRONG:  `<button class="button" on:click={displayobj = 0}>Clear</button>`

CORRECT: `<button class="button" on:click={() => displayobj = 0}>Clear</button>`

BTW, the reason that `Clear` button didn't work is because what you gave Svelte in the `on:click` was not an executable function, so the JS code failed with a runtime exception at that point and after that nothing would run until you reload the app.

All in all, it looks like you have not gone through the Svelte tutorial, but tried to use it without understanding the fundamentals of it. So I'd recommend that you got through the tutorial first - it's pretty quick if you are familiar with JS already: https://svelte.dev/tutorial/basics

And for your education I threw together a starter file for creating a calculator app: https://svelte.dev/repl/e6e34f4957204498bfa6e14645ff6044?version=3.44.2

After the first half of the tutorial lessons you should be able to understand it, modify it and finish it up.